# CSS: Ignoring divs height when floating

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to display some pictures. All of them have the same width but different height.
I'm trying to do something like: [image: correct image]

Every picture's class name is *pic*

```
<img class = "pic" src = .... />
```

In the stylesheet I specified the float:left attribute:

```
.pic{
    float:left
}
```

The end result isn't the one expected while every row is vertically aligned after the highest div from the row before: [image: wrong]

Is there a way to solve my problem in pure cross browser css?

Comment: This is an excellent example of how to write a question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with no extra markup with CSS3 `column-count`, assuming you at least have a single containing element.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/NcxPr/

HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
<img class="image" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/205/494701000_744cc3a83a_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4028/4287569889_f6a4fca31b_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2340/2421926504_d8509d0a98_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/197/503792921_fedf8ba47e_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1153/741035029_f394e11a1f_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6213/6243090894_8b8dd862cd_z.jpg" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm2.staticflickr.com/1339/1157653249_dbcc93c158_z.jpg?zz=1" />
<img class="image" src="http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2570/4220856234_029e5b8348_z.jpg?zz=1" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#container {
    column-count: 3;
    column-fill: balance;
    column-gap: 10px;
    width: 330px;
}

.image { 
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great! The only downside of this is that I have to know and specify all images' height.

Comment: @lonut No. I just did that in the demo to give the images height. It's not necessary.

Comment: @lonut I updated it with some real images and removed the heights.

Comment: Awesome; This is why I like stack I get to learn new ways (and delete my old fashioned answers)

Answer (score 2):

Are you able to add some extra markup?

If yes, you could make 3 columns with floating divs:

```
<div class="column">
    <img src="1.jpg" />
    <img src="4.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="column">
    <img src="2.jpg" />
    <img src="5.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="column">
    <img src="3.jpg" />
    <img src="6.jpg" />
</div>
```

Or just use jQuery to do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you can't do this with CSS2/3.

There *is* [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/), a fairly small script that emulates `float: top;` and works well.

Comment: That sounds great but I'm trying to avoid JS while I'm working with JSF2

Comment: Just to add to your selected answer, make sure to specify a `min-width` for the container. Your columns will overflow if you don't.