# How should I display this horizontal irregular blocks of display?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html, asp.net-4.0

Please see this website:

http://www.rivvir.com/blog/

You can see that the blocks of the columns are all irregular. For eg. 1st column might be less in height, 2nd might be big and so on. But when the 2nd row of data starts it starts right below where the 1st row 1st column's data got over.

How do I achieve this type of display in Asp.Net? Assume I am using repeater for this purpose. Can you please suggest how would I do that?

Comment: You might be interested in [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out ThinkingStiff's answer to this question:
[CSS: Ignoring divs height when floating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843465/css-ignoring-divs-height-when-floating)

It can be done using CSS, but uses browser-specific CSS selectors. 
Take a look at the jsfiddle he linked to, as it shows the full css-markup for cross-browser support.